# Substraction of integer values in string variables in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a website in asp.net and have this problem:

```
 string price = row["Price"].ToString();
 string discount = row["Discount"].ToString();
```

This code is for taking data from a `DataTable` and it is working correctly. Both are floating point values(12,50.75...). In my program I want to subtract "discount" from "price" and assign the result to a new string. Suppose string price contains `50` and string discount contains `23.5`, then I want `26.5` in the new string. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: why are you not converting the values to floats? then do the math then convert it back to string...

Comment: Thank you.Let me know how can i convert it into float.Visual studio is not showing an option for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you the below code:

```
    string strPrice =  row["Price"].ToString();
    string strDiscount =row["Discount"].ToString();
    string strFinal = (Convert.ToDouble(strPrice) - Convert.ToDouble(strDiscount)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need double.Parse to make them number and perform arithmetic operations on them.

```
double price = double.Parse(row["Price"].ToString());
double discount = double.Parse(row["Discount"].ToString());

double amount = price - discount;
```

Comment: you need a leading paranteces after Parse in second line dude.

Answer (score 0):

```
string newPrice = (double.Parse(price)-double.Parse(discount)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string strDiff = (Convert.ToDouble(row["Price"].ToString()) - Convert.ToDouble(row["Discount"].ToString())).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do like this way

```
double amount=(convert.toDouble(row["price"].tostring()))-(convert.toDouble(row["Discount"].tostring()));

string Totalamount=amount.tostring();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert double string variable to double using Convert.ToDouble or using double.Parse() function.
for difference between these two [check](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32885/Difference-Between-Int32-Parse-Convert-ToInt32-and)

```
double price ,discount,amount;
string result = null;
price = double.Parse(row["Price"].ToString());
discount = double.Parserow["Discount"].ToString());
amount = price - discount;
string result = Convert.ToString(amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 double amount=(convert.todouble(row["price"].tostring()))-(convert.todouble(row["Discount"].tostring()));
```